# No Such Module Moya

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swifty-json, moya

I am Using xcode 13.4.1 and installing pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
pod 'Moya', '~> 15.0' these pods successfully i can't import these pods in my class.

[image]

Comment: Did you open the `.xworkspace` and not `.xcodeproj`? Does Moya appear in the file list of "Xcode" on the right panel?

Comment: yes i open .xworkspace and Moya appear in the file

Comment: switch to SPM, especially if using an M1

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
pod "Moya", '~> 13.0'
```

Comment: Not resolved again same issue.